# adding 60 amp service to a movable shed

Tags: shed, temporary

Thank you in advance for any help. My wife has a shed about 15' from our 50 amp rv hookup. Can I install an inlet plug on the shed that feeds a 60 amp spa panel that goes to a breaker box in the shed and use a 20' 50 amp RV extension cord? All she is wanting is some lighting and an outlet or two. It will be unplugged when not in use. I realize none of it will probably meet code, just don't want to burn the shed down. I have some #6 wire leftover from the hot tub installation. Any suggestions are welcome, or let me know if its the dumbest idea you ever heard.

Comment: Having a bigger panel than the breaker feeding it is not a problem.  How movable is the shed or how often do you move it?  If it is going to in one place(not moved every week),  you might want/need a couple of ground rods also(code required for detached sheds/buildings).  The used of an extension will leave to the experts.   The extension use is iffy, for 15 feet should be easy to buried a proper line.

Comment: If truly all she wants is lighting and an outlet, and you're going to run an extension cord on the floor regardless, why not just use a regular 120V extension cord plugged into an outlet?  Why do you need a panel, and 60 amps? You could use a regular outdoor-rated outlet.    For that matter, what will she be plugging into the outlets that could not potentially use low voltage or even batteries?

Answer (score 2):

A lot of people get confused with "panel size rating", i.e. the redline "never exceed" maximum amps a panel can handle without catching on fire.  It's very similar to the speed rating on your car tires; yes they say 112 MPH but you're not obliged to drive that fast :)

The most important characteristic of any panel is enough breaker spaces to serve your present and future need for circuits.  There's a loose correlation to panel max amps; for instance there's 70A-max panels never get larger than 4 spaces, and any 40-space panel will be 200/225A redline.  So usually, you end up with a panel whose redline maximum amps are larger than you'll actually be feeding it with.  That is fine.   It's like you'll never drive 112 MPH and that's fine.

And by the way, there's no such thing as a 60A panel.  Yes, they make (70A) 2-space panels with 60A breakers for spas, but you don't actually need one - an exterior disconnect is not required on an outbuilding (nor a vehicle, since I gather you're putting wheels under it to dodge the Building Code?  Well, you didn't dodge NEC. NEC applies to buildings on wheels aka RVs.)

If you want the spa panel as a way to get "whole building GFCI protection" on the cheap, I recommend against this, because several circuits can have enough natural leakage to trip that GFCI, and now you have to put on your galoshes!  Because Murphy's Law says it will be night, and it will be raining :)  Use per-circuit GFCIs, either as breakers or receptacles at the first outlet.  The latter is much cheaper.

> I have some #6 wire leftover from the hot tub installation.

Well that's fine for "inlet to internal panel" wiring within the structure. But for the actual flexible cord connecting the inlet to the main building, you will need **cordage**.  You can't take #6 NM or UF and slap plug and socket on it and call it a cord; you'll crack the conductors and then they'll overheat.

The good news is, the cordage only needs to be #8, since you can rely on its 75C temperature rating.  Honestly for the stated requirements, you could just wire a 120V subpanel in the structure and feed it from a 120V/15A circuit with a normal extension cord.  You only need to haul 240V out there if you're planning to run multiple circuits and/or a mini-split.

As always, my advice for "I own the wrong wire, can I use it wrong?" is to sell that on Craigslist and buy the right thing (optionally: also on Craigslist).

And in the future, patronize your local family-owned hardware store or lumberyard, who will often and cheerfully sell you wire *by the foot* at exactly the length you need, and not leave you hanging with half a roll you have no use for. I compared 10' actual of 10/3 *at my local "overpriced, no apologies" family owned hardware store, with Home Depot's price on a "short 15 foot short spool" of the stuff, and the local hardware was cheaper by half.  Because the hardware was marking up off the 250' roll price, and the box stores shamelessly overcharge for short spools.

Oh, and on RV outlets and feeders, 6-6-6-6 aluminum is your friend.

Comment: Would the OP need ground rods if using an extension for the shed?

Comment: thank you for the response. The panel I have for the shed is a Siemens 125 amp 8 space 16 circuits. So I would be better off skipping the spa box for the GFCI and get a breaker with the built in GFCI? The cord I plan on using is made for RV's with 50 amp service, I am not planning on making my own extension cord. I will only need a couple of circuits for lights and two outlets. I just do not want to run extension cords all over the inside. The #6 wire I have will run from the new inlet port in conduit thru the wall into the panel.

Comment: @Bob sounds great.  Honestly I would use a GFCI receptacle at the first outlet and use the Load terminals to protect other receptacles,  but not the lights. Both to save money and to keep the lights off GFCI.  Since you are hardwiring them into the walls, lights don't benefit much from GFCI and a trip putting you into darkness sucks.

Comment: @crip659 nope! If it moves around no ground rods needed. That's covered by the ground to the RV panel.